# Importing JointJS in JavaScript using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jointjs, lit

I am aware that questions on this topic have already been answered, but since they are a little old and none of the solutions apply to my problem *(which is bugging me for days)*, I decided to come forward to ask the community.

I am trying to build a web component for diagramming using Lit and JointJS.

Basically I created a new Node.js project using WebStorm and installed all the dependencies I think I need. My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "project-name.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "web-dev-server --node-resolve --open --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@web/dev-server": "^0.1.34",
    "@types/backbone": "~1.4.15",
    "@types/jquery": "~3.5.13",
    "@types/lodash": "~4.14.178"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jointjs": "^3.6.1",
    "lit": "^2.4.0",
    "backbone": "~1.4.1",
    "jquery": "~3.6.1",
    "lodash": "~4.17.21"
  }
}
```

To test if this setup is working I used the 'Hello World'-example from the lit.dev website:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="module" src="project-name.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<simple-greeting name="World"></simple-greeting>
</body>
```

project-name.js:

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import * as joint from 'jointjs'; // causes problems

export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
    static styles = css`p { color: blue }`;

    static properties = {
        name: {type: String},
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = 'Somebody';

        console.log(joint); // would like to test-print the object
    }

    render() {
        return html`<p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>`;
    }
}
customElements.define('simple-greeting', SimpleGreeting);
```

When starting up the web-dev-server using `npm start` and looking at the console output of the site, I get the following error when importing jointJS the way I did:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../../jquery/dist/jquery.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at util.mjs:2:8)
```

I already looked up this error but it seems odd to me that this occurs on installed libraries. I really don't want to touch the installed libraries code.

How do I get this JointJS import working properly with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with configuration for `"@web/dev-server"`, but I tried your code using `vite` and everything is working fine.

I just installed `vite` via `npm`, and added `"dev": "vite",` to my `package.json`.

Just from looking at the documentation from `"@web/dev-server"` quickly, it seems like it tries to use es modules for everything, so maybe some extra configuration is needed via `"@web/dev-server"` or `rollup` to transform packages in `node_modules`.

Just as an aside, the `JointJS` dependencies will be installed via npm when you add `JointJS`, so you don't need to add `lodash`, etc separately.